# Sequence contains no elements. Below is my code snippet. I dont know what is wrong

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

```
string flexParameterSQLType = RepositoryContainer.GBM.Flex.Admin_FlexTriggerTypeParameters
   .First(x => x.RecordID == dtoFlexTriggerEventParameter.FlexTriggerTypeParameter_RecordID).SqlType;

if (flexParameterSQLType != null)
{

    if ((flexParameterSQLType == "datetime" || flexParameterSQLType == "date") && dtoFlexTriggerEventParameter.Value != null && dtoFlexTriggerEventParameter.Value != "")
        dbFlexTriggerEventParameter.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtoFlexTriggerEventParameter.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    else
        dbFlexTriggerEventParameter.Value = Convert.ToString(dtoFlexTriggerEventParameter.Value);
}
```

Comment: "Sequence contains no elements" is pretty self-explanatory.  If you don't know which sequence is causing the problem, hover your mouse over all of those terms (RepositoryContainer, GBM, etc.) and see which one is empty.  Or, break up your terms into separate variables, and check each one individually.

Comment: It could also simply be that the filter you're providing to your `First` call is filtering out all of the records.

Comment: By the way `Convert.ToDateTime(...).ToString()` is horrible if you are dealing with proper SQL parameters, what are you converting it back to `string` for